# Filter by multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got data.frame like below

```
ID  country age
1   X   83
2   X   15
3   Y   2
4   Y   12
5   X   2
6   Y   2
7   Y   18
8   X   85
```

I need to filter rows for age below 10 and at the same time above 80. 
How can I do it in the simplest way? For one condition I can use `filter(data.frame, age > 80)` but I don't know how to do it for two conditions at the same time?

Comment: Use `|` for or. like `df1 %>% filter(age < 10 | age > 80)`

Comment: Another option would be `filter(dat, !between(age, 10, 80))`

Comment: @talat answer is great, especially for combining with filters on other columns!
say you want  to exclude that age range AND filter by country `filter(dat, age < 10 | age > 80 & country == X)` won't work, as it will select ALL X.
`filter(dat, !between(age, 10, 80) & country == X)` will do it. Might need dplyr::between if plyranges or data.table are loaded too

Answer (score 34):

I'm not sure from the question if you want the values between 10 and 80 or those below ten and above 80.  If you want those between, you can put multiple arguments in `filter`.  If you want those below 10 and above 80 you can use `|` as an "or" operator:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  filter(age > 10,
         age < 80)

data %>%
  filter(age < 10 | age > 80)
```

Comment: Your use is incorrect for OP's need. the comma acts as an AND not as an OR. It needs to be < 10 and > 80

Comment: @anba maybe I don't understand the question.  Is the goal to have a data set of 10<data<80 or is it to have a data set of data<10 and data>80?  I'll edit the answer for both.

Comment: @Ben G I want to filter out data for age <10 and >80. In other words, I need to get data only for rows 1,3,5,5,8 from my example data.frame.

Answer (score 15):

Following may help you here too using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
##Creating variable dat here which has values in it.
dat <- read.table(text = "ID country age
1   X   83
2   X   15
3   Y   2
4   Y   12
5   X   2
6   Y   2
7   Y   18
8   X   85",
                  header = TRUE)

dat %>%
  filter(age<10 | age>80)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
        dat <- read.table(text = "ID country age
                         1   X   83
                         2   X   15
                          3   Y   2
                          4   Y   12
                           5   X   2
                           6   Y   2
                           7   Y   18
                           8   X   85",
                           header = TRUE)

 x<-filter(dat, dat$age>80&dat$age<10) 
 x
```

Now, you can either use the OR (|) condition or you can use the AND (&) condition based on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: As written, this answer cannot possibly work. Age cannot be both greater than 80 and less than 10 (I believe you meant to use `|`, not `&`). Moreover, one should avoid using `$` inside of `filter`. The data frame's column names can be referred to directly, without using `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution for those committed to sticking with base R:

```
# Read in the data
data <- read.table(
  text = "ID  country age
  1   X   83
  2   X   15
  3   Y   2
  4   Y   12
  5   X   2
  6   Y   2
  7   Y   18
  8   X   85",
  header = TRUE
)

# Filter according to conditions
data[data$age < 10 | data$age > 80,]
```

Output:

```
  ID country age
1  1       X  83
3  3       Y   2
5  5       X   2
6  6       Y   2
8  8       X  85
```

You can put as many conditions as needed and use parentheses to clarify order of operations. For example, if we wanted to add another condition to ensure that the country must be `X` (in addition to the conditions posed in OP's question):

```
data[(data$age < 10 | data$age > 80) & data$country == "X",]
```

Output:

```
  ID country age
1  1       X  83
5  5       X   2
8  8       X  85
```

The purpose of the comma at the end of the conditions is to indicate that we are applying the conditions to the rows of the data frame. To filter columns in addition to rows, clarify those columns after the comma:

```
data[data$age < 10 | data$age > 80, c("ID", "country")]
```

Output:

```
  ID country
1  1       X
3  3       Y
5  5       X
6  6       Y
8  8       X
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in `subset()` function. It works like the dplyr's filter function mentioned in the other answers. You can join the two conditions "*smaller than 10*" OR "*larger than 80*" with the logical operator `|` (OR).

```
data <- read.table(
  text = "ID  country age
  1   X   83
  2   X   15
  3   Y   2
  4   Y   12
  5   X   2
  6   Y   2
  7   Y   18
  8   X   85",
  header = TRUE
)

subset(data, age < 10 | age > 80)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) from dplyr.

```
x<-filter(dat, dat$age>80|dat$age<10)
```

Comment: Please, improve your answer with some explanation for everyone.