# Filter a group of a data.frame based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am looking for an elegant way to filter the values of a specific group of big data.frame based on multiple conditions.

My data frame looks like this.

```
data=data.frame(group=c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"), 
                time= c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3), rep(3,3)), 
                value=c(0.2,1,1,0.1,10,20,10,20,30))

  group time value
1     A    1   0.2
2     B    1   1.0
3     C    1   1.0
4     A    2   0.1
5     B    2  10.0
6     C    2  20.0
7     A    3  10.0
8     B    3  20.0
9     C    3  30.0
```

I would like only for the time point 1 to filter out all the values that are smaller than 1 but bigger than 0.1

I want my data.frame to look like this.

```
  group time value
1     A    1   0.2
4     A    2   0.1
5     B    2  10.0
6     C    2  20.0
7     A    3  10.0
8     B    3  20.0
9     C    3  30.0
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R dplyr - filter by multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041946/r-dplyr-filter-by-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Not really. I had to edit my question to make it more clear. Thank you for your comment. It was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you have too much free time and you decided to avoid `dplyr`:

```
ind <- with(data, (data$time==1 & (data$value > 0.1 & data$value < 1)))
ind <- ifelse((data$time==1) & (data$value > 0.1 & data$value < 1), TRUE, FALSE)
#above two do the same

data$ind <- ind
data <- data[!(data$time==1 & ind==F),]
data$ind <- NULL

  group time value
1     A    1   0.2
4     A    2   0.1
5     B    2  10.0
6     C    2  20.0
7     A    3  10.0
8     B    3  20.0
9     C    3  30.0
```

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr` you can do

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% filter(!(time == 1 & (value <= 0.1 | value >= 1))) 

#   group time value
# 1     A    1   0.2
# 2     A    2   0.1
# 3     B    2  10.0
# 4     C    2  20.0
# 5     A    3  10.0
# 6     B    3  20.0
# 7     C    3  30.0
```

Comment: Dear Ric thank you for the neat answer. Do you have an idea of how I could eliminate the values from the next time points as well? That is another question indeed

Comment: @LDT I see you created another post on this question. For helping future viewers, I suggest you to revert your edit to the original question and accept the best answer among the two. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option would be to use `subset` twice and then append the results in a row wise manner.

```
rbind(
  subset(data, time == 1 & value > 0.1 & value < 1),
  subset(data, time != 1)
)

#    group time value
# 1     A    1   0.2
# 4     A    2   0.1
# 5     B    2  10.0
# 6     C    2  20.0
# 7     A    3  10.0
# 8     B    3  20.0
# 9     C    3  30.0
```